# Is there a way to read the images from the "samples" folder if OpenCV was installed with pip?

Tags: python, opencv, pip

Is there a way to read the images from the "samples" folder if OpenCV was installed with pip?

I am trying to use one of the images (e.g., [`box.png`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/box.png)) from the [`samples`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/data) folder of the OpenCV package with the following Python code

```
cv2.imread(cv2.samples.findFile('box.png'))
```

However, I am getting the following error

> OpenCV samples: Can't find required data file: box.png in function 'findFile'

Why? And how can I solve it?

I am using the following versions of the packages (for reproducibility), which were installed with `pip`:

```
opencv-contrib-python         3.4.2.16
opencv-contrib-python-nonfree 4.1.1.1 
opencv-python                 3.4.2.16
```

And I am using Python 3.7.5.

Please, don't tell me to use another version of OpenCV or any other library.

Comment: Those python packages don't include any sample data. You'd have to fetch the data yourself, and put it [in some location the function seaches](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.8/d6/dba/group__core__utils__samples.html#ga3a33b00033b46c698ff6340d95569c13).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem on my Mac. So to solve this I used

```
cv2.samples.addSamplesDataSearchPath
```

I manually added a new path to the sample data, for instance

```
cv2.samples.addSamplesDataSearchPath('.../Desktop/opencv-4.4.0/samples/data')
```

If you can't find your samples/data folder, you can download it from:
[github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/data](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/data)

Here you can find more information about this function:
[docs.opencv.org/master/d6/dba/group__core__utils__samples.html](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/dba/group__core__utils__samples.html)

Answer (score -2):

here is the example of the code

```
cap = cv2.imread("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Program2/step3/box.png")
```

you can change this part C:/Users/user/Desktop/Program2/step3/ to the folder that include a picture

Comment: This is not what I am asking.

Comment: damn. just put your directory file to the code. it simple bruh dont make it hard